# React state.map return empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created an application using the covid19 api. I store state and function in the context api. I want to create an apexchart, but the dailydata map that keeps it in the same place returns an empty array. I need to enter my options data with dailyDate

```
const {country} = useContext(countryContext);
const [dailyData,setDailyData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchdata = async () => {
      const data = await dayOneAllStatus(country);
      setDailyData(data);            
  };  
  fetchdata();
  },[country])

const [options,setOptions] = useState({
    chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'area'
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      stroke: {
        curve: 'smooth'
      },
      xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        categories: dailyData.map(item => item.Date)
      },
      tooltip: {
        x: {
          format: 'dd/MM/yy'
        },
      },
});
const [series,setSeries] = useState([
    {
        name: 'Vaka',
        data: dailyData.map(item => item.Confirmed)
      }, {
        name: 'İyileşen',
        data: dailyData.map(item => item.Recovered)
      },
      {
        name: 'Ölüm',
        data: dailyData.map(item => item.Deaths)
      }
]);

return (
      
  <div id="chart">
  <Chart options={options} series={series} type="area" height={350} />
</div>
    
)
```

dailyData console.log example

```
    Array(426) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
  [0…99]
[100…199]
[200…299]​
[300…399]
[400…425]
length: 426
```

Comment: The argument you pass to `useState` is the initial state, i.e. state on the first render. In your case you're fetching the daily data from an API, so it won't be set on first render. You can use an effect that, when the daily data changes, it calls `setSeries` with those `dailyData.map` values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call useState, the parameter that's passed in is the initial-value. So when the function re-runs because `dailyData` has updated, the values in options and series don't update.

If you're not actually using `setSeries` and `setOptions` anywhere, you're better off leaving them as normal variables that are computed using `dailyData`:

```
const {country} = useContext(countryContext);
const [dailyData,setDailyData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchdata = async () => {
      const data = await dayOneAllStatus(country);
      setDailyData(data);            
  };  
  fetchdata();
  },[country])

const options = {
    chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'area'
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      stroke: {
        curve: 'smooth'
      },
      xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        categories: dailyData.map(item => item.Date)
      },
      tooltip: {
        x: {
          format: 'dd/MM/yy'
        },
      },
};
const series = [
    {
        name: 'Vaka',
        data: dailyData.map(item => item.Confirmed)
      }, {
        name: 'İyileşen',
        data: dailyData.map(item => item.Recovered)
      },
      {
        name: 'Ölüm',
        data: dailyData.map(item => item.Deaths)
      }
];

return (
      
  <div id="chart">
  <Chart options={options} series={series} type="area" height={350} />
</div>
    
)
```

Comment: Thanks to your reply, I understood the mistake I made and corrected it, I am grateful.